# Get all instance variables declared in class

Tags: ruby

Please help me get all instance variables declared in a class the same way `instance_methods` shows me all methods available in a class.

```
class A
  attr_accessor :ab, :ac
end

puts A.instance_methods  #gives ab and ac

puts A.something         #gives me @ab @ac...
```

Comment: I still have no idea what this second part is asking, or how it relates to needing to get all instance variables from an object.

Comment: Instance variables aren't declared anywhere. This question makes no sense.

Comment: "name" variable is dynamically created too.

Answer (score 86, accepted):

You can use [`instance_variables`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Object.html#method-i-instance_variables):

```
A.instance_variables
```

but that’s probably not what you want, since that gets the instance variables in the *class* `A`, not an instance of that class. So you probably want:

```
a = A.new
a.instance_variables
```

But note that just calling `attr_accessor` doesn’t define any instance variables (it just defines methods), so there won’t be any in the instance until you set them explicitly.

```
a = A.new
a.instance_variables #=> []
a.ab = 'foo'
a.instance_variables #=> [:@ab]
```

Comment: Is there any method in ruby which count undefined variables. 
As we have provided list in attr_accessor. So somewhere their entry has already be done.
Thanks For answering

Comment: @AkshayVishnoi `attr_accessor :foo` just generates `def foo; @foo; end` and `def foo=(val); @foo = val; end`. Nothing is stored anywhere.

Comment: thanks for your help but still i am not finding my way to answer of my question.
Like sir if i have class 'Player' containing a variable name. Now i have initialized 5 objects. Now if i want to find number of players having name "Ak" then how would i generate this function dynamically in a Module say "MyModule", which is included in the class "Player"

Thanks for your co-operation

Answer (score 17):

If you want to get all instances variables values you can try something like this :

```
class A
  attr_accessor :foo, :bar

  def context
    self.instance_variables.map do |attribute|
      { attribute => self.instance_variable_get(attribute) }
    end
  end
end

a = A.new
a.foo = "foo"
a.bar = 42
a.context #=> [{ :@foo => "foo" }, { :@bar => 42 }]
```

Answer (score 1):

It's not foolproof - additional methods could be defined on the class that match the pattern - but one way I found that has suited my needs is

```
A.instance_methods.grep(/[a-z_]+=/).map{ |m| m.to_s.gsub(/^(.+)=$/, '@\1') }
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to get a hash of all instance variables, in the manner of attributes, following on from Aschen's answer you can do

```
class A
  attr_accessor :foo, :bar

    def attributes
    self.instance_variables.map do |attribute|
      key = attribute.to_s.gsub('@','')
      [key, self.instance_variable_get(attribute)]
    end.to_h
  end
end
a = A.new
a.foo = "foo"
a.bar = 42
a.context #=> {'foo' => 'foo', 'bar' => 42}
```

Answer (score 0):

Building on the answer from @Obromios , I added `.to_h` and `.to_s` to a class to allow for pleasant, flexible dumping of attributes suitable for display to an end user.

This particular class (not an ActiveRecord model) will have a variety of attributes set in different situations. Only those attribs that have values will appear when printing `myvar.to_s`, which was my desire.

```
class LocalError
  attr_accessor :product_code, :event_description, :error_code, :error_column, :error_row 

  def to_h
    instance_variables.map do |attribute|
      key = attribute.to_s.gsub('@', '')
      [key, self.instance_variable_get(attribute)]
    end.to_h
  end

  def to_s
    to_h.to_s
  end
end
```

This allows me to put this simple code in a mailer template:

```
Data error:   <%= @data_error %>
```

And it produces (for example):

```
Data error:   {"event_description"=>"invalid date", "error_row"=>13}
```

This is nice, as the mailer doesn't have to be updated as the LocalError attributes change in the future.

Comment: This didn't quite work for me.

`NameError: `name' is not allowed as an instance variable name`

You have to send a symbol to self.instance_variable_get.
Example: `self.instance_variable_get(:@name)`

Answer (score 0):

If you run byebug you can run simply run `instance_variables` to get the list generated at runtime.

Might be a new feature. Running ruby 3.2.2