# How to print the instance variables of a class with name and value?

Tags: ruby

I've got an ActiveModel class `SupportCase` which has certain instance variables (created with `attr_accessor`).

For a given object of that class, how I can print out the names of its instance variables as well as the values.

I've tried:

```
support_case.instance_variables.each { |a,b| puts "#{a} #{b}" }

support_case.instance_variables.each { |a| puts "#{a} #{support_case.send(a)}" }
```

The latter didn't work since it creates the call `support_case.@var` whereas it should be `support_case.var`. So I could strip the `@` but
there has to be some cleaner way of doinf what I want to do, right?

Thanks!

Comment: Try to follow this http://stackoverflow.com/a/37543312/5949678 Hope It will help you

Comment: Thanks, Divya, will have a look!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to Divya Sharma, I've found the method I was looking for:

```
#instance_variable_get
```

I used in the following way (regarding my question):

```
support_case.instance_variables.each { |ivar| puts "#{ivar}: #{support_case.instance_variable_get(ivar)}" }
```