# Why do I not see instance variable after creation? (attr reader)

Tags: ruby

I have following code, which creates instance variables dynamically. If the instance variable does not exist, I use the no method error to create the `attr_reader` and `attr_writer` methods dynamically. All works fine, but I don't understand why I don't see the `@anything` instance variable after having created the first `attr_reader`.

```
require "pry-byebug"

class UberHash
  attr_accessor :color
  def initialize
    @color = nil
  end

  def method_missing(m, *args, &block)
    if m.match(/=/)
      puts "create attr writer"
      self.instance_variable_set("@#{m[0..-2]}", args[0])
    else
      puts "create attr reader"
      self.instance_variable_get("@#{m}")
    end
  end
end

uber_hash = UberHash.new
puts "call 1 .................."
p "uber_hash.anything: #{uber_hash.anything}"
p "uber_hash.inspect: #{uber_hash.inspect}"
p uber_hash.anything = "hola"
p uber_hash.inspect
```

With following results:

```
call 1 ..................
create attr reader
"uber_hash.anything: "
"uber_hash.inspect: #<UberHash:0x00007f851b1e41a8 @color=nil>"
"#<UberHash:0x00007f851b1e41a8 @color=nil>"
create attr writer
"hola"
"#<UberHash:0x00007f851b1e41a8 @color=nil, @anything=\"hola\">"
```

After creating the first instance variable `anything`, with the method instnace_variable_set, I understand that I create an attr_reader right?

Why do I not see the `@anything` instance variable if I inspect the instance?

Answer (score 0):

You don't see the instance variable in the first inspect. You expect it the be there because in previous line you call `uber_hash.anything`, right?

Well, the `uber_hash.anything` call evaluates the `else` in the `#method_missing` conditional: `self.instance_variable_get("@#{m}")` - that's why no instance variable is set.

Also, in `#method_missing` conditional you print two messages: `puts "create attr writer"` and `puts "create attr reader"` - they are wrong. It should be: `puts "create instance variable"` and `puts "read instance variable"`

Comment: oh I see first point. Second point: I thought the attr_reader & attr_writer methods are created, since I can use later on `ubser_hash.anything = "hola"`. That's why I thought that they were created. The `def anything=(arg)` method should be somehow created, right?

Comment: Yes, but I would advice against doing so, because metaprogramming is tricky. It looks like you are trying to build something similar to OpenStruct. Do you know OpenStruct? https://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.5.1/libdoc/ostruct/rdoc/OpenStruct.html

Comment: No worries, never gonna use it for production, just learning for fun. I still don't see the point of making things so complex. Maybe in some years. I checked OpenStruct, nice one. Thanks a lot for your help, the first point helped me a lot.

Answer (score 0):

> After creating the first instance variable anything, with the method `instnace_variable_set`, I understand that I create an attr_reader right?

No, that is not correct.  Your class never creates (or runs) `attr_reader`.  Try this (after running your example commands)

```
p( uber_hash.methods - Object.new.methods )
```

and you see only the methods additionally defined in your class be `[:color, :color=, :method_missing]` in your class.

The method `:color` is defined because of `attr_accessor :color`.  Remember `attr_accessor` etc is just a shortcut to define methods.
By contrast, the method `:anything` is **not** defined because your class has never defined the method.
Instead, in your class, every time a method `uber_hash.anything` is called, `uber_hash.method_missing` is run and does the job, that is, manipulation or viewing of the instance variable `@anything`.

Secondly, while `instance_variable_set` does set a value to an instance variable (and creates it if it does not exists), `instance_variable_get` refers to it only if it exists, else returns nil and does *not* create an instance variable. That is why `@anything` is created after `instance_variable_set`, but not just after `instance_variable_get`.  Try this to see the point (after your definition of the class).

```
class UberHash
  def test_pr
    print 'color='; p instance_variable_get("@color")
    print 'other='; p instance_variable_get("@other")
    p instance_variables  # => @other is not defined
    print 'other='; p instance_variable_set("@other", 99)
    p instance_variables  # => @other is NOW defined
  end
end

uber_hash.test_pr
```

Consequently, the behaviour you see is perfectly legitimate.

Note: [this past answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11925855/get-all-instance-variables-declared-in-class/11925908#11925908) explains it.